# Exporting COLUMNS of information to new sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a school report card where grades can be entered (A, B, C, and D from drop down menus) on an input sheet, and then the information pertaining to different students is exported to separate sheets.

I found this macro (below) for exporting information from an input sheet to separate sheets in a workbook, but the problem is that it works in rows and not columns. It takes the name in column A (say, A3), creates a worksheet based on that name and exports the information from row 3 along with it, so B3, C3, etc. based on the range variable that you input into the module.

What I would like to do is take the names from a row, rather than a column, and export the information **below** the name to a separate sheet (with the name being the title of the new sheet). So, as you can hopefully see in the screenshot, my students' names run from D7 to Q7, and the grades for the first student run from D8 to D63.

[Screenshot][1]

I've tried changing all the vcol commands to row commands and vice versa, but I can't seem to debug it. I'm very interested in becoming a better programmer, but I have to admit I'm basically a novice. Any advice?

```
Sub parse_data()
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vcol, i As Integer
    Dim icol As Long
    Dim myarr As Variant
    Dim title As String
    Dim titlerow As Integer
    vcol = 1
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
    title = "A1:C1"
    titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
    icol = ws.Columns.Count
    ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
    For i = 2 To lr
        On Error Resume Next
        If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
            ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
        End If
    Next
    myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
    ws.Columns(icol).Clear
    For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
        ws.Range(title).AutoFilter Field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
       If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
            Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).name = myarr(i) & ""
        Else
            Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        End If
        ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
        Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
    Next
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: To save people having to go to a (potentially virus-infected) 3rd-party site before they can answer your question, please paste whatever is at the end of the link into the question itself.  (If it is an image it will then be hosted at a site where the image will remain available to future readers of the question even if the 3rd-party site ceases to exist.)

Comment: @A.S.H - I would, but I have no idea what that website is, so don't want to go there to take a copy of the image (or whatever).  I think the OP needs to put the image into the question (thus hosting it at the SO section of imgur), then we can edit the question to inline it if appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although there may be some "Filter By Rows" method I'd go with a `Dictionary` approach

```
Option Explicit

Sub parse_data()
    Dim studsSht As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim stud As Variant

    Set studsSht = Worksheets("Sheet1") '<--| change "Sheet1" to your actual students grades sheet
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") '<--| instantiate a Dictionary object
        For Each cell In studsSht.Range("D7:Q7").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues) '<--| loop through students names (change "D7:Q7" to your actual range with students names)
            .item(cell.Value) = .item(cell.Value) & cell.EntireColumn.Address(False, False) & "," '<--| add or update the dictionary entry whose key is the current student name with its corresponding column address
        Next
        For Each stud In .keys '<--| loop through unique students names
            Intersect(studsSht.UsedRange, studsSht.Range(Left(.item(stud), Len(.item(stud)) - 1))).Copy Destination:=GetSheet(CStr(stud)).Range("A1") '<--| copy its columns to correspondingly named sheet starting from cell A1
        Next
    End With

    studsSht.Activate
End Sub

Function GetSheet(shtName As String) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetSheet = Worksheets(shtName)
    If GetSheet Is Nothing Then
        Set GetSheet = Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.count))
        GetSheet.Name = shtName
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot; this works well. It makes no difference how many students I have in the row, it creates the correct number of sheets without an error message. However, it doesn't preserve the width of the cells. Anyway, I forgot to mention that as well as the information pertaining to each student to be carried to another sheet, I'd also like the 'common' information from the input page (i.e. A1 to C63) to be carried over to every sheet so that the grades make sense. Would it be too much to ask to make this work? I'm not really at the level of multiple functions in one macro.

Comment: You are welcome. Since my answer solved your _original_ question you may want to mark it as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thank you. As for the _additional_ issues let me think over them in the meanwhile...

Comment: Sorry, yes. I spotted that when I went to search for the answer, and I saw that there were responses with ticks. Here you go. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Davie, you marked as accepted another answer. Anyhow if that one is the one you actually chose then that's fine.

Comment: They both work well. It's interesting how different codes (what appear to be wildly different codes) can perform the same function. I think I prefer the fact that I can apply this macro to any of my classes, regardless of the number without having to edit the macro. The only thing is, I can look at the other macro and understand how it works. Your macro has just created a lot of study for me! But I suppose that's the point of me being here.

Comment: _"I think I prefer the fact that I can apply this macro to any of my classes"_, so what does it mean? Which macro do you prefer?

Comment: Oh, I see. I can't accept both? If I click the tick on his, then it disappears from yours. Well that's a bit shit. I mean, they are both perfectly great answers. What I meant was that, if I have 7 students in a class, then with the other macro I have to edit the range variable from D7:Q7 to D7:J7, and for any other class with a different number of students, I have to edit the macro again. With yours I can apply the range D7:Q7 to the macro, apply to every report template, and I don't get an error message, regardless of how many students are on the input page. By that, I mean I prefer this one.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you can't accept but one answer, which is the one that best fits your need. But you can upvote the accepted answer _and_ any other answer if you find them _useful_ (see help - asking)

Answer (score 0):

The code seems a bit fancier than what your specifications call for, so I've simplified it down a bit in my answer here to make it a bit more understandable. The first for loop simply removes duplicates in your headings (in your case, if you had more than one student with the same name, it would only make one new sheet for that name).

Because your use case seems to call for a unique identifier for each student in your data anyway, I've removed that (and related code) to make it simpler for you. The simple subroutine below should solve your problem for a set number of students. If you plan to expand your students in the future, it would be easy to go in and make that part dynamic, but for now you can just edit the range in `Set studentsRange = masterSheet.Range("D7:Q7")` to always correspond to where your students' names are.

```
Sub CreateIndividualReportCards()
    Dim masterSheet As Worksheet
    Set masterSheet = Sheets("Sheet1") 'This is the title of the sheet where your bulk data is
    Dim studentsRange As Range
    Set studentsRange = masterSheet.Range("D7:Q7") 'This is the range of your headings, in your case student names

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To studentsRange.Columns.Count
        If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & studentsRange.Cells(i) & "'!A1)") Then 'This checks to see if a sheet for the student already exists
            Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = studentsRange.Cells(i) & ""
        End If
        Sheets(studentsRange.Cells(i) & "").Columns.ClearContents 'In case the sheet already exists with old data, this line clears that old data and in order to repopulate with the new data from the masterSheet
        studentsRange.Cells(i).EntireColumn.Copy Sheets(studentsRange.Cells(i) & "").Range("A1") 'This copies the student's grades to the new sheet
    Next i

    masterSheet.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't expect such a fast response. Thanks a lot - It works perfectly. I see what you mean about having to edit the macro for the size of the class, but that's no big deal. However, me being a newbie to this, I forgot to mention that as well as the information pertaining to each student to be carried to another sheet, I'd also like the 'common' information from the input page (i.e. A1 to C63) to be carried over to every sheet so that the grades make sense. Is this too much of a pain?